# List box with checkboxes + Command binding not firing in empty space click

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am sure that I am missing something small here, but somehow not able to figure out. I have a list box bound to a collection in my view model. In my datatemplate for listbox item I have a checkbox. The check box has command binding to a ICommand in view model. When displayed some checkbox have text enough to fully cover the width of list box item others do not so a blank space at end is left behind.
 The behavior I want is that when the user clicks anywhere in the list box item (even in last empty space) the command should get invoked. The problem is that currently I am only able to invoke the Command in view model if user clicks only in area where checkbox is there (if user clicks on left empty space the command is not invoked)

I have tried various options of using a toggle button with control template as check box. The toggle button covers the whole item space and binds to command as required but when I use check box in the toggle button's control template the Command binding stops working.

Below is my XAML. Any suggestions/pointers should help.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Selected,Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding Caption}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" >
          <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IListDataConverter}">
              <Binding Path="."/>
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
        </CheckBox>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

- Girija

Comment: Does checkbox get checked/unchecked if you click on empty space?

Comment: Yes,  BUt that is because I am using that IsSelected bind to both Checkbox IsChecked and ListBoxItem.IsSelected. That is expected behavior. BUt in this case (when I click on empty space) only the check box state changes but command is not invoked. But I need to invoke the command everytime as I do need it for some other logic execution. That somehow I am not abel to achieve.

Comment: In practise, will be better to use ScrollViewer and ItemsControl instead of ListBox.

Comment: How would that help ?

Comment: I'll show example, just one more question. Does IsChecked property must always change on CheckBox after click? Or you try to separate Command invoke and CheckBox's IsChecked state?

Comment: Try commenting line `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>` in ListBox Item style.

Comment: @Spawn :  Yes it must change. The reason it is bind to the property is because to enable the click on empty space as well. I have my business logic on Command binding. The Is Selected is only used internally for visual states and not used by my business logic. My business logic relies on the parameters passed to it. So yes the Command Invoke and Checkbox IsChecked state is separate.

Comment: @user1672994 :  Removing/commenting the Horizontal alignments Does not help. Same issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Well, simple example without double/triple logic with IsSelected on ListBox and bindings it to CheckBox and also to ViewModel.

In XAML i've create ScrollViewer, ItemsControl.

```
<ScrollViewer Width="200">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:SelectableObject">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </CheckBox.Content>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In codebehind:

```
private ICommand _itemSelection;
public ICommand ItemSelection => _itemSelection ?? (_itemSelection = new DelegateCommand(_ => MessageBox.Show("Click")));

public MainWindow()
{
    Items.Add(new SelectableObject("Item 1"));
    Items.Add(new SelectableObject("Item 2"));
    Items.Add(new SelectableObject("Item 3"));
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

public ObservableCollection<SelectableObject> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SelectableObject>();
```

And simple class

```
public class SelectableObject : DependencyObject
{
    public SelectableObject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected",
        typeof (bool), typeof (SelectableObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this and get back

Comment: I did try this using Scroll viewer and Items control. But the same issue persists. It only works if in click on the check box. If I click on the area to right of the item (away from checkbox) it does not work

Comment: It can't be true.... I've added TextBlock as CheckBox content, maked background blue, after clicking on white space on left side of TextBlock, command is worked.

Comment: Maybe you have some extra styles that retemplates ContentControl and something else?

Comment: I donot have any style templates. I have styles for listbox and listboxitem though. One nore clarification though: Why is my code not working. Also when I replace the DataTemplate by a ToggleButton and inside the toggle button I am placing a checkbox, I bind the ToggleButton Command to my viewmodel, but the click never hits my ICommand. Why is this behavior ? - Girija

Comment: Ok, did you tried to use my example on clear project? If it work how you want, then we can try find out why it's work incorrect in current project.